# Windows 8 cannot connect remotely to Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

I have installed Windows Server 2012 and then configured remote applications. At first it was working fine and I could be able to connect remotely and run remote applications from Windows 8 clients. But after few days the following error occurred:

```
Remote Desktop Connection  
This computer can't connect to the remote computer. Try connecting again.   
If the problem continues, contact the owner of the remote computer or your network administrator.
```

However I still can connect from Windows 7 without any problem. Only Windows 8 has a problem and cannot connect remotely. Neither remote apps nor RDP is working.

Comment: Can you try pinging the remote machine from Windows 8 (make sure it's not a connectivity problem)? Also, can you launch eventvwr.exe and open Application and Service Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> RemoteApp and Desktop Connections -> Admin and see if there are any errors? Also check TerminalServices-* (under Windows) on both the client and the server machine to look for more errors.

Answer (score 1):

1. Logon to the server locally
2. Click Start, Run, type 'tscc.msc /s' and click OK
3. In the Terminal Services Configuration snap-in double-click Connections, then RDP-Tcp in the right pane
4. Click the Network Adapter tab, select the correct network adapter and click OK
5. Make sure that you can establish an RDP connection to the server
   The change takes effect immediately. No need for a restart.

Comment: tscc.msc is working on Server 2003 but I've got "Windows cannot find 'tscc.msc'" on Server 2012. Do you know what's the equivalent on 2012?

Comment: @Pacerier run `MMC` from the start menu.  Then go to `File` and `Add/remove snapin` (or something to that effect) and look for it by name.